# Find position in 3D numpy array where value of 2D array is first exceeded

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find the position in a 3D numpy array where a 2D array first exceeds the value in the 3D array. E.g.

```
import numpy as np
array_3D = np.random.rand(10, 3, 3)
array_2D = np.random.rand(3, 3)

np.argmax(array_2D > array_3D)
```

I get the result 0, but I want a 2D array i.e. essentially argmax results for each grid cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, that is what the axis parameter is for:

```
>>>np.argmax(array_2D > array_3D,axis=0)
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 0]])
```

otherwise it runs across the flat array.

Answer (score 0):

`np.where(array_2D > array_3D)` will give you 3 arrays with the coordinates of the points you are looking for. If you are looking for the first point:

```
x =  np.where(array_2D > array_3D)[0][0]
y =  np.where(array_2D > array_3D)[1][0]
z =  np.where(array_2D > array_3D)[2][0]
```

Certainly not the most elegant, thought, as you won't have directly the first point.